# Where are installed apps from the store, how to change default installation path?

Tags: disk, installed-programs

I'm brand new to Ubuntu (official 18.4, GNOME desktop), and don't get it yet. I've installed some apps from Ubuntu Software, but they seem to save on sda (main disk, there is also system on this device) and I would like them to install on sdb (1TB HDD), because I'm about to run out of space quickly if things will stay this way. Is there a way to change installation path of those programs (ideal solution would be different location for each program)?
Effect of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA ADATA SU800NS38 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  128GB  128GB  primary               boot, lvm


Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1023MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0,00B  1023MB  1023MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 127GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  127GB  127GB  ext4
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Since this is a Q&A site, please ask one question at a time on this site. You have two separate questions. I suggest, you edit this question removing the second part of your question and posting it as a separate question.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please also run `sudo parted -l` in a terminal window, copy the results, then come back here and add them to your question with [edit]. Please do not use Add Comment as Comments have no formatting, and the formatting is very useful in looking at results.

Comment: And, please do look for questions involving 'desktop launcher'  to answer your question regarding the Prusa app.

Comment: Are you sure that installed applications are really the problem? Ubuntu applications tend to be quite small if you are doing it right. Most folks' /home directory, with stored movies and music, tend to be much larger...and much easier to move to a different location.